# Different language (esp. Rcpp) not printing output when knitting an Rmarkdown chunk

Tags: r, knitr, r-markdown, rcpp

This works in Rstudio, and I get the live preview directly in the document when running the chunk. However, when I knit the .Rmd to .html I only get an echo of the code and no output.

````
```{r engine='Rcpp'}
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
int main() {
  return 4;
}

/*** R
main()
*/
```
````

If I do the same with python, however, I get the proper output when knitting:

````
```{r engine='python'}
print("abc")
```
````

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately, the comment markup (`/***R */`) execution does not get retained due to the way it is executed as you noticed. You could say this is an `rmarkdown` buglet; however, the `/***R */` is meant more for an embedding a call during interactive development.

Also, the use of `int main()` is a big no-no. To quote Dirk:

> You can't just drop *R* context into a standalone `main()` as you need *R* for *R* context.

As a result, I've opted to change the function name to `toad()`.

To achieve the same result and to be true to literate programming, each section should be embedded in separate code chunks. That is, you must create an *Rcpp* code chunk---preferably with cache enabled---and an *R* code chunk that contains the actual function call.

e.g.

````
---
title: Test Doc
author: JJB
date: 6/9/2017
output: html_document
---


```{Rcpp hpc-code, cache = TRUE}
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
int toad() {
  return 4;
}
```

```{r interactive-output}
toad()
```
````

[image: Sample output]

Comment: +1 for helping me with a similar issue. Apparently, writing the C++ function in a `{Rcpp cache = TRUE}` chunk works better and is cleaner than heading the chunk with `{r name, engine='Rcpp'}` and then referencing `name` in the other R chunk calling the function.